# Как отобразить стили, используя styled-components в react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

То ли что-то не понимаю, то не знаю уже, но при отображении Square(мои стили), ничего не отображается, тупо белый фон, web compiled successfully показывает. Убираю , всё отображается. Что-то делаю не так? В консоли nanoid is not a function и react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Styled(View)> component

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import styled from "styled-components/native";

const Square = styled.View`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  backgroundColor: red;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Компоненты</Text>
      <Square />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```